# How do I add content to my page via a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like a text box on my page that behaves like this: when the enter button is pressed, the contents of the textbox is added to the page. I would also like a `<br>` break after each submission.

How do I do this in HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly create the `<textarea>` and the `<button>` elements, then create or choose preferably a `<div>` and give it a class, I'll use `class="content"`.

```
<div>
   <textarea></textarea>
   <button>Add content</button>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Then use this simple script which is executed on load. Basically when the `<button>` is pressed the function firstly checks if the `<textarea>` is empty or not while stripping it from spaces at the beginning and end. If the `<textarea>` is not empty its content is appended to the `<div class="content">` inside a `<p>` element followed by a `<br>`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
      toAdd = $.trim($('textarea').val());
      if(toAdd !== ""){
         $('.content').append('<p>'+ toAdd + '</p><br>');
      }
   });
)};
```

Don't forget to link jQuery library to the document.

Comment: @AHolasek Are you properly linking jQuery library to your document like that? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` If so, can you check the console for error?

Comment: The exact same code works on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreIDK/rdthog3y/)

Comment: Yes, I linked my app.js properly... I'm asking a friend I have at devleague.com how to do it. He should know.

Comment: You also have to put this one before the other script `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`